# Unknown bson type DECIMAL128 in vertx mongo client

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, vert.x

How can data type be enforced during insertion or update in MongoDB, I am using older mongo java driver which does not support DECIMAL128, So during find query I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown bson type DECIMAL128`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like version 34 of Vert.x uses the MongoDB Async drivers version 3.6.3 (see pom.xml file). This supports Decimal128 just fine.

So, I guess my answer is: Use the latest Vert.x version.